# how to connect localhost wcf service with asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-4.0

i have just created one wcf service for serve some functionalities to my local web project. here is my localhost wcf service web config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeWeb" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/staff_care_wcf_ws/RestServiceImpl.svc"
        behaviorConfiguration="WebHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb"
        contract="SC_WCF.IRestServiceImpl" />
    </client>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

and finally this is my local web site web config to deal with local hosted wcf service.

```
<system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeWeb" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/staff_care_wcf_ws/RestServiceImpl.svc"
        behaviorConfiguration="WebHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb"
        contract="SC_WCF.IRestServiceImpl">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
     <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

how ever this works not fine. the following error occurs like :

```
The endpoint at 'http://localhost/staff_care_wcf_ws/RestServiceImpl.svc' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings."}
```

what going wrong here please help me out this guys.....

**update**

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using WCF (and .NET Framework 4.0) today? Both are decades old and are effectively obsolete (not to mention WCF configuration being a huge PITA - as you're seeing)

Comment: @dai help me out. this one web project important to me..

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the **webHttp** in the endpointBehaviors node, because the base address used in IIS for service deployment is not "http://localhost/staff_care_wcf_ws/RestServiceImpl.svc". Your WCF service has only one basicHttpsBinding endpoint. Your client configuration file should look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="LargeWeb" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/Service1.svc"
          behaviorConfiguration="WebHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="webHttpBinding_IService1"
          contract="ConsoleApp1.IService1">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WebHttp">
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webScriptEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
        </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**If the WCF service is deployed to IIS, its base address should be as follows:**

[image]

[image]

**So your WCF configuration file has the same effect as the following configuration file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

ProtocolMapping can simplify the configuration, it will help you generate a basicHttpsBinding endpoint.

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

**UPDATE**

**Your configuration file is a bit confusing, I suggest following the steps below to recreate a WCF service deployed in IIS:**

Create a WCF Service Application project:

[image]

This is the project directory:

[image]

The interface of the service is stored in the IService file, and the implementation class of the service is stored in the Service1 file.

Replace the content in web.config with the following configuration information:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="WcfService2.Service1"
                     behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="basicHttpBinding"
                          contract="WcfService2.IService1"
                          bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        
            <bindings>
                <basicHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="LargeWeb" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    </binding>
                </basicHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
    

    </system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The above configuration information will generate a basicHttpBinding endpoint.

Publish it to IIS:

[image]

Use a browser to access the service:

[image]

Use Add Service Reference to generate proxy classes to call services:

[image]

This will automatically generate the proxy class and configuration file, you can call it directly.

Comment: If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: how did you do set application pool to WCF. well i have this list of my default appplication pool. see update...

Comment: We do not need to set the application pool, you can try to publish a template project deployed in IIS.